# The Cantor Set length is zero, why? Limits

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

**My question is after the construction of the Cantor set which you might want to skip over that part**. This question is not philosophical at all it is pertinent to my understanding of measure and space. Please If you think this is absurd, don't bother replying.

**Construction of the Cantor Set:**

We will denote the cantor set as $\mathfrak{C}\subset\mathbb{I}$
 , $\mathbb{I}=[0,1]$
  as defined in section 1, as mentioned above we construct $\mathfrak{C}$
  by removing middle third of the set (not including its endpoints). We denote this first slice in $\mathbb{I}$
  as $$\mathfrak{c_{1}}=\left[0,\frac{1}{3}\right]\cup\left[\frac{2}{3},1\right]=\mathbb{I}\setminus\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right)$$
 Next we cut out the middle third of each interval in $\mathfrak{c_{1}}$
 , that is the intervals $\left[0,\frac{1}{3}\right]\text{ and }\left[\frac{2}{3},1\right]$
  so we get 
$$\left[0,\frac{1}{3}\right]\to\left[\frac{0}{9},\frac{1}{9}\right]\cup\left[\frac{2}{9},\frac{3}{9}\right]=\left[0,\frac{1}{9}\right]\cup\left[\frac{2}{9},\frac{1}{3}\right]$$
 $$\left[\frac{2}{3},1\right]\to\left[\frac{6}{9},\frac{7}{9}\right]\cup\left[\frac{8}{9},\frac{9}{9}\right]=\left[\frac{2}{3},\frac{7}{9}\right]\cup\left[\frac{8}{9},1\right]$$

So we write $$\mathfrak{c_{2}}=\left[0,\frac{1}{9}\right]\cup\left[\frac{2}{9},\frac{1}{3}\right]\cup\left[\frac{2}{3},\frac{7}{9}\right]\cup\left[\frac{8}{9},1\right]$$

Hence we have that $\mathfrak{c_{2}}$
  is the union of $2^{2}$
  intervals all of which are of the form $[k/3^{2},(k+1)/3^{2}]$
 , if we continue this process for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
  we find that each $\mathfrak{c}_{n}$
  is constructed of $2^{n}$
  intervals all of the form $[k/3^{n},(k+1)/3^{n}]$
 , and $\mathfrak{c}_{n+1}$
  will be obtained by taking the middle third out of each interval in $\mathfrak{c}_{n}$
 . The cantor set is what remain after we continue this processv for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
  and then take the intersection over every $\mathfrak{c}_{i}$
 , or we could write $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\mathfrak{c}_{i}=\mathfrak{C}$$
  Where $\mathfrak{C}$
  is the Cantor set.

**My Question:**

Why do we say that the Cantor set has no length? I get that the length of $\mathfrak{c_1}=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^1$ and that the length of $\mathfrak{c}_n=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ so 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n= 0$$

Since, $\mathfrak{C}\subseteq\mathfrak{c}_n$ if follows that $\mathfrak{C}$ has a length of zero. Or, even you could argue that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{k}{3^{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{k+1}{3^{n}}=0$$
Since, the endpoints of each interval in $\mathfrak{c}_n$ converge to the same point each interval will become a single point in interval $\mathbb{I}$, and a single point $x\in\mathbb{R}$ has a measure of zero, i.e. $d(x,x)=0$. So, summing up distances of each intervals (of which there must be $2^{\aleph_0}$ many) in $\mathfrak{C}$, you get that the distance is zero.

**It is the concept of the limit and space that is tripping me up**. Even if $n\to \infty$ $\frac{k}{3^n}\neq 0$ unless $k=0$ (in which case $\frac{k+1}{3^n}\neq 0$). In my mind $\frac{k}{3^n}$ can never equal $\frac{k+1}{3^n}$ because $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k+1$ is $k$'s successor (thus they are clearly not equal), so in a world of only the natural numbers it is clear that $k$ and $k+1$ don't occupy the same space. However, in $\mathbb{R}$ if we take the limit $n \to \infty$ of both $\frac{k}{3^n}$ and $\frac{k+1}{3^n}$ they end up equaling the same point in space, even though there numerators are different. Clearly, a difference of $1$ is negligible  in respects to $\infty$. But in my mind the every point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is distinct, if you changed the trillionth decimal place in $\sqrt{2}$ and left every other digit intact, this new number would not share the same space (point) as $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. And in this same vein I feel like $\frac{k}{3^n}$ and $\frac{k+1}{3^n}$ will never be equal, they will differ by some decimal. And ultimately that would mean that the Cantor set has a distance/measure.

Can someone explain to me why we would think differently about this? I am taking a first course in Analysis but please feel free to go beyond this If it will give a more rigorous explanation for why the cantor set has no distance. (Also, point out any abuses in language that I might have made.) Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "summing up distances of each intervals" ?

Comment: @Stefan I mean that each interval in $\mathfrak{c}_n$ is of the form $I_j=\left[\frac{k}{3^n},\frac{k+1}{3^n}\right]$ the distance of each particular $I_j$ would be the distance from the two endpoint $d(\frac{k}{3^n},\frac{k+1}{3^n})$ if the two end points both converge to the same point as $n\to \infty$ then $d(\frac{k}{3^n},\frac{k+1}{3^n})=0$, that is that each interval in $I_j \in \mathfrak{c}_n$ will have a length of zero. Let us denote the length of $I_j$, which we found above as $d(I_j)$ (sorry this is an abuse of notation). Then $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}d(I_j)=0$ that is what I meant.

Comment: One, might also notice that the infinity $\infty$ in the sum in the comment above is not simply the limit of $n\to \infty$ in $n$ in the natural numbers. Because for each time you remove a middle third from an interval in $\mathfrak{c}_n$ you are left with $2^{n+1}$ intervals in $\mathfrak{c}_{n+1}$, thus if we do this for all $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ you will have $2^{\aleph_0}$ intervals in $\mathfrak{C}$ so the infinity in the sum is not just a natural number, at least I don't think.

Answer (score 8):

I propose you trying to work this out with the following approach, which uses pretty elementary properties of Borel measure on the real line:

To form the Cantor set you "removed":

$$1\;\;\text{interval of length}\;\;\frac13\\2\;\;\text{intervals of length}\;\;\frac19\\\ldots$$

All in all, you removed *disjoint* intervals of total length

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{n-1}}{3^n}=\frac12\frac{\frac23}{1-\frac23}=1$$

Since everything's happening in the unit interval, what is left (properties!) of it after the above removal, i.e. Cantor's set, has length $\;1-1=0\;$

Comment: Thanks this also makes perfect sense to me as well. However, it doesn't explain to me why the Intervals in $\mathfrak{C}$ would end up have a length of zero if they are defined in the way that the book I am reading defined them. Of course the advantage of this proof is that we didn't have to define the intervals of $\mathfrak{c}_n$ like the other author did which avoids question of why the endpoints would converge to the exact same point.

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully this removes one source of confusion:

*The Cantor set contains no intervals.*

That is, there is no set of the form $(a,b)$ contained in the Cantor set. The reason is that rational numbers with a $1$ in their triadic expansion are dense in $[0,1]$, so at some step in the construction of the Cantor set there are points removed from $(a,b)$.

Therefore it is not right to say that the "intervals in $\mathfrak{C}$ have length zero." There are no intervals in $\mathfrak{C}$. The Cantor set shouldn't be thought of as some union of limits of intervals of the form $[k/3^n, (k+1)/3^n]$, it is much subtler than that.

Comment: I think this is getting at the heart of my question. But, let me read some more about the density of a set. I think this has me going in the right direction thanks!

Comment: But since there are nowhere dense sets of positive measure, this is only part of the truth.

Comment: This is precisely how I was taught to prove it and I think it's the most informative approach. To have positive measure, a subset of $\mathbb R$ must have at least one interval as a proper subset and C simply has none.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 What you have said is not true. The set of irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ has measure $1$ but contains no intervals. My answer was only intended to clear up a particular point of confusion in the original post.